# Вывод контента. Как лучше?

Tags: php

Представим, что мы используем MVC подход и передаем во вьюху некоторый массив данных. Эти данные, на сколько я знаю, можно вывести как минимум двумя путями:

1)

```
<div class="content">
foreach($array as $value){
echo '
<div class="box">
<div class="title">'.$value['title'].'</div>
<div class="content">'.$value['content'].'</div>
</div>';
}
</div>
```

2)

```
$content = '';
foreach($array as $value){
$content .= '
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">'.$value['title'].'</div>
    <div class="content">'.$value['content'].'</div>
    </div>';
    }

<div class="content"><?=$content ?></div>
```

Так вот, какой из этих способов формирования контента более правильный? На сколько мне известно оператор echo при каждом вызове увеличивает время работы скрипта (по крайней мере в консоли), так будет ли более быстрым вариант использования второго способа, где echo вызывается всего раз. И как вообще принято писать в проектах?

UPD: Проверил скорость работы двух вариантов вывода. Результаты более чем впечатляющие. Разница в скорости работы примерно в 100 раз. Вот сам скрипт если что.

```
<?php
$start = microtime(1);
for($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++){
    ?>
    <?= '+'; ?>

<?php }
    $finish = microtime(1)-$start;
    $start = microtime(1);
    $content = '';
    for($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++){
        $content .= '-';
    }
    echo $content;
    $finish2 = microtime(1)-$start;
    echo 'Время выполнения через echo: '.$finish.'сек ';
    echo 'Время выполнения через конкатенацию: '.$finish2.'сек';
```

Comment: Первый проще дебажить, второй для извращенцев мазахистов.

Comment: С ошибкой второй способ написал изначально я. Теперь по прежнему для извращенцев?) И если да, то аргументируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @makbeth - прошу прощения, писал с телефона и не увидел там echo - эти оба варианта дебажить в IDE практически нереально. Используйте способ, который вам предложил @andreyqin - это лучшее что можно сделать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как вариант, делать php-вставки в разметку или использовать (написать свой) шаблонизатор:

```
<div class="content">
    <?php foreach ($array as $value) { ?>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></div>
            <div class="content"><?php echo $value['content']; ?></div>
        </div>';
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Если использовать данный способ, то вызовов echo будет как минимум в два раза больше. А это отразится на скорости. Или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: Это экономия на спичках

Comment: сам всегда так делаю

Comment: В общем понятно мнение. Буду в дальнейшем использовать именно этот способ. Спасибо!

Comment: @makbeth - вот так ещё можно чутка сократить код:

    <div class="title"><?=$value['title']?></div>
    <div class="content"><?=$value['content']?></div>

Comment: @ua6xh, если будет отключена директива short_open_tag, то такой вариант не сработает.

Comment: @makbeth, ну может вы проиграете микросекунды... подумаешь.. подключаете Memcache и сайт летает

Comment: @makbeth, попробуйте представить, сколько вы выиграете в одной загрузке страницы и сколько загрузок страницы должно быть, чтобы компенсировать время на поддержку такого кода (и сколько отработка echo занимает от всего скрипта целиком).  
@mountpoint, никак серебряная пуля нашлась.

Answer (score 3):

Если, как в первом варианте, использовать echo, то это лишние вызовы функций и работа со стеком параметров.
Если, как во втором случае, конкатенировать мелкие значения в одну переменную, то это лишние выделения памяти в общей куче.

Вариант с вставками кода PHP

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $value['title']?></div>
```

оптимальнее, потому что количество echo меньше, а для накопления результата используется буфер вывода, на который и так уже память выделена.

В подтверждение моих слов приведу следующий упрощённый код, который применяется в фреймворках, использующий шаблонизаторы класса "pure PHP" :

Класс View - это компонента View по шаблону проектирования MVC - она передаёт пользовательские параметры $varsв шаблон в виде переменный в локальной области видимости. Файл view.php - это шаблон, то есть файл PHP, в котором непосредственно создаётся фрагмент кода HTML.

```
<?php
class View {
   function render($vars) {
      extract($vars); // перевести массив в набор локальных переменных
      ob_start(); //открыть буфер
      include('view.php');
      return ob_get_clean(); // закрыть буфер и вернуть его содержимое
   }
}

// где то в другом месте делается так
$view = new View;
echo $view->render(array('array' => array('title'=>'title1', 'content'=>'content1'));
?>
```

Как видите, в методе render используется буфер.

В целом в фреймворках таких вызовов сотни по коду и экономия как времени, так и памяти значительная. Если рассматривать не один вызов, а сотни в секунду на протяжении суток, то сервер будет меньше грузить процессор и потребует меньше оперативной памяти, значит можно будет либо использовать более слабый и дешёвый сервер, либо обслуживать больше запросов в секунду и радовать высокой скоростью ответа бОльшее количество посетителей сайта.

Смысел ясен?

Comment: Не совсем. Допустим вызываем метод render. Он принимает массив данных, которые в шаблоне нам надо отобразить. Отображать как будем? Через перебор массива скорее всего. Опять на тот же вопрос напарываюсь. Или может я чего не понимаю? Кстати по поводу скорости... Замерил я тут давеча два варианта вывода... Готовый скрипт прикреплю к своему вопросу. Если запустите его например в консоли, то увидите разницу в скорости работы примерно в 100 !!! раз.